# Using Eulervm font with chemformula package

Tags: chemistry, eulervm, euler, chemformula

I want to see how various chemical equations look using the `euler` or `eulervm` font, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it (or if it's even possible).

[The documentation for chemformula](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/chemformula/chemformula_en.pdf) indicates that I can set font by using a `font-family` parameter with  `\setchemformula` .

I have used this code in the header of my tex file

```
\usepackage{eulervm} 
\setchemformula{font-family=eulervm}
```

This is in the body of the document.

```
\begin{equation} \label{keqequation}
    \dfrac{\ch{[B][K]}}{\ch{[A]}} = K_{eq}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

You can see that the `K_{eq}` is in `eulervm` font, but the `[K]` is not.

I have also tried:

```
\setchemformula{font-family=euler}
\setchemformula{font-family=euler-vm}
```

without success

I can, however, change the font using

```
\setchemformula{font-family=lmss}
```

which suggests that I'm not doing anything horribly wrong.

Any thoughts on how to pull this off?

Also, I know that I could get the euler font simply by NOT using chemformula's `\ch` command in this situation, but there will be other times when I want to use the features of the `\ch` command, so I'd like to know if it's possible to use euler inside of `\ch`.

Thanks for any thoughts!

Here is a complete stripped down version of what I described above.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\setchemformula{font-family=eulervm}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{keqequation}
   \dfrac{\ch{[B][K]}}{\ch{[A]}} = K_{eq}
\end{equation}
```

\end{document}

Comment: Welcome! Please always post a complete, compilable minimal document rather than mere fragments of code as it is much harder to work with the latter.

Comment: The problem, I think, is that **eulervm** does not provide a font in the output encoding **chemformula** requires. So **chemformula** looks for a font in `OT1` or `T1` encoding but Euler doesn't support that. Also, the family name is not `euler-vm` or `euler` but `zeur`, for example, But unless **chemforuma** can use encoding `U`, I think you are out of luck here.

Comment: Note that **chemformula** letters will generally look like maths *operators* e.g. if you compare `\sin`, you'll see it uses the same font.

Comment: @cfr sorry about that. I edited the post. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no usable version of Euler for OT1 or T1 encoding. The fonts have `♭` and `♯` in the slots for `[` and `]`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, but you need extra care, because the available Euler fonts have quite a nonstandard layout.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{zeu@@Scale}{\let\zeu@@Scale\@empty}{}
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{zeur}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{zeur}{m}{n}{
   <9-> \zeu@@Scale zeurm10
   <6-9> \zeu@@Scale zeurm7
   <-6> \zeu@@Scale zeurm5
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{zeur}{b}{n}{
   <9-> \zeu@@Scale zeurb10
   <6-9> \zeu@@Scale zeurb7
   <-6> \zeu@@Scale zeurb5
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{zeur}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * zeur/b/n}{}
\makeatother

\setchemformula{font-family=zeur}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{keqequation}
\dfrac{[\ch{B}][\ch{K}]}{[\ch{A}]} = K_{eq}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The brackets must be outside `\ch`, because the Euler font doesn't have them in the standard slots.

[image]

If you have the Neo Euler font (see https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf), you can use it with `unicode-math`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\setmathfont{Neo Euler}
\setchemformula{font-spec={Neo Euler}}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{keqequation}
\dfrac{\ch{[B][K]}}{\ch{[A]}} = K_{eq}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]